# TypeScript doesn't understand that object is defined when checking from variable

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When I'm checking if object is declared directly it works just fine obviously, but I'm wondering if it's possible to extract this check into a variable and make TypeScript to still understand it.

```js
import React from "react";

interface Props {
  obj?: {
    val: string;
  }
}

function A({ obj }: Props) {
  const hasObj = !!obj;

  return (
    <>
      <p>This works fine:</p>
      <div>{!!obj && obj.val}</div>

      <p>This throws an error (Object is possibly 'undefined'):
      <div>{hasObj && obj.val}</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Is it possible to make it work that way?

Comment: why not just use `<div>{obj?.val}</div>` ?

Comment: it's just a simple example, I need it for more complex checks

Comment: Consider trying type predicates. They only work with functions, but they might help you. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it, TypeScript isn't smart enough to "follow" variables like that, i.e. that `hasObj` would always mean that `!!obj` unless something mutates or reassigns `obj` in the meanwhile.

If it suits your program, you can do a guard like

```
function A({ obj }: Props) {
  if (obj === undefined) {
    return;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <p>This works fine:</p>
      <div>{obj.val}</div>

      <p>This throws an error (Object is possibly 'undefined'):
      <div>{obj.val}</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

which does work, and TypeScript correctly infers `obj` can't possibly be null past that early return.